# Granting Lync Polcies Via AD Group Member using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, policy, lync-2013

I am trying to grant MS Lync policies based on AD group membership. So far I have arrived at the following command but it fails to execute as desired.

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Name_Of_AD_Security_Group" | Grant-CsPersistentChatPolicy -PolicyName "Name_Of_Policy"
```

I know that the `Grant-Cs...` command will take a pipeline input but I suspect the AD output does not match the required input for the Lync command.

Would anyone have a better command of know of a way to transform the output into the correct input format?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to Lync Powershell modules, but I noticed that the command you're wanting to run accepts output from Get-CsUser on its [TechNet page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj204907.aspx).

See if this works:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Name_Of_AD_Security_Group" | Get-CsUser
```

If it doesn't, try:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Name_Of_AD_Security_Group" | Select-Object SamAccountName | Get-CsUser
```

Based on which works(if either do):

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Name_Of_AD_Security_Group" | Get-CsUser | Grant-CsPersistentChatPolicy -PolicyName "Name_Of_Policy"
```

or

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Name_Of_AD_Security_Group" | Select-Object SamAccountName | Get-CsUser | Grant-CsPersistentChatPolicy -PolicyName "Name_Of_Policy"
```